# C++/CLI DLL project stops linking after conversion from VS2008 to VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, lnk2001

I converted a perfectly working Managed C++ DLL project that uses Unmanaged C++ LIBs from VS2008 to VS2010. Beforehand I separately rebuilt the LIBs with VS2010 (they are part of another project that I have no authority over). However, after conversion my managed DLL project stopped linking giving me few dosen of LNK2001 error messages (see the sample below). All errors about "std" entities defined within "string" and "iosfwd" headers. Which compiler/linker settings am I missing?

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

```
Auxiliary.lib(Error.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) bool __cdecl std::operator!=<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class td::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,char const *)" (__imp_??$?9DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@1@@std@@YA_NAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@0@PEBD@Z)

Auxiliary.lib(Error.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl std::operator<<<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_??$?6DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@1@@std@@YAAEAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AEAV10@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@0@@Z)

Auxiliary.lib(Error.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned __int64 const std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::npos" (__imp_?npos@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@2_KB)

Auxiliary.lib(Error.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Lock(void)" (__imp_?_Lock@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAXXZ)

Auxiliary.lib(Error.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Unlock(void)" (__imp_?_Unlock@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAXXZ)

Auxiliary.lib(Error.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl std::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::str(void)const " (__imp_?str@?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEBA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@2@XZ)

Auxiliary.lib(Error.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl std::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(int)" (__imp_??0?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAA@H@Z)

Auxiliary.lib(Error.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::substr(unsigned __int64,unsigned __int64)const " (__imp_?substr@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEBA?AV12@_K0@Z)

etc...
```

Comment: By "Managed C++", do you mean the "Managed Extensions for C++"? The thing that was declared dead in 2001 and replaced by C++/CLI?

Comment: Are you sure that you have replaced the Auxiliary.lib with the one you have compiled with VS 2010?

Comment: Yes, it was recompiled with VS 2010

Comment: When you link the VS2008 project you can create a map file and look which library defines these symbols. This may give a hint...

Comment: It wasn't according to the mangled names.  You still have a .obj or .lib file that was compiled by VS2008 or earlier.  You'll have to rebuild it.

Comment: @KerrekSB : Released in 2002, declared dead in 2005. ;-]

Comment: This was posted awhile ago, however it would be nice to have it solved for other people running into the same problem. Would it be possible for you to provide the linker's command line in the projects properties? I am curious if you have a /NODEFAULTLIB switch set for one of the msvc runtime libraries. I ran into this issue after migrating to visual studio 2010 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it (thanks Hans Passant for the tip!) I had a few files that were still built by VS2008 and that caused the issue. Thanks to everyone who bothered to add a comment.