# LNK2001 error when building project in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2012, lnk2001

I am trying to Migrate VS2008 solution to VS2012 Express. Here when I try building a project(.dll)

I get multiple LNK2001 errors.
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base_secure::_Container_base_secure(void)" (_*imp*??0_Container_base_secure@std@@QAE@XZ)

This project has dependency on another project which is a static library.

Another thing to notice if I change the project type that I am building to .lib I get no errors.

Comment: Did you search for that error message here? There are dozens of hits for `error LNK2001: unresolved external` here and in Google. Surely one of the should give you an idea of what might be causing this like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525256/c-cli-dll-project-stops-linking-after-conversion-from-vs2008-to-vs2010?rq=1) (from the `Related` list to the right ====>>>>>>).

Comment: You are going to have to rebuild **all** the libraries you use.  So that they will use the VS2012 version of the C++ standard library, not the VS2008 version.